# Explain this rewrite rule

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

Could somebody explain these rewrite rules in English please so I can get a better understanding of the syntax - my initial understanding is the following:

If the URL starts or ends with a slash then display http://www.example.com/:

```
RewriteRule ^/$                 http://www.example.com/ [P,L,QSA,NC]
```

If the URL starts with a slash followed by a string not including a slash then a dot and not including another string with a slash then redirect it to http://www.example.com/$1

```
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+\.[^/]+)$   http://www.example.com/$1 [P,L,QSA,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

The fist regex says: it has to start AND end with the slash. So only the pure "/" matches here. If that matches, the redirected url is delivered via the builtin proxy module instead of redirecting the browser. All query parameters are appended again and no further rewriting is done in that request. The also mentioned NC (case insensitity) is meaningless here.

Your description of the second expression is correct. The prevention of matching the slashes serves to prevent accidential matching of sub directories. So only requests to objects in the top level directory match. The same additional rules apply as in the first expression, and again the case insensivity is meaningless.